# How is it possible to access property of an Object directly without making reference to an Object while calling a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which got referenced from some other file

```
define(function() {
    return function service1(){

       function setting1(){
           return{
               settings: {
                   url: '',
                   timeout: 1000,
                   type: 'GET',
                   headers: {'xyz' : null},
                   xhrFields: {
                       isRegistered: false
                   }
                   switch: ON
               }
            };
       }     
        this.calls1 = {
            details: setting1()
        };

    };
});
```

//the below function call is made from another file.
    this.service1.details();
How does the above `service1.details()` works?

Comment: And what is `define()`? Is that angularjs?

Comment: i don't think it does anything

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough of the code to answer the question with any degree of accuracy

Comment: @A.Wolff define is AMD/CommonJS module loader

Comment: @dandavis this is working code only this is I have modified some values of properties

Comment: @JaromandaX I was told that it is typical and basics related to service call using jQuery without the use of AJAX. I was not able to find any answer to it so far.

Comment: I have no idea how this relates to jQuery - because you've not posted enough code to even suggest jQuery is involved at all in your issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, I have a moron TL in Team who said it is basic jQuery thing without the use of AJAX, he wasted ample amount of my time too, later I found out that this is possible as there is framework built internally for easy development.